# How to change API KEY in flutter project with firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, api, key, api-key

please help me:
I've uploaded my login google firebase project to github, but yesterday i receive this from github to my email:

**"GitGuardian has detected the following Google API Key exposed within your GitHub account.
Secret type: Google API Key"**

Should i delete ios app & android app from firesabe and create it again? to make a new api key and make "git ignore" and "push" in this new case?

note: the api_key from my .Json is not the same that the api key web from my firesabe setting project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YhZ0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to delete your project and start again, What you have do is to make sure that you map your api key in .gitignore to avoid it being uploaded to git. If **GitGuardian**  already deleted that is good for you bcz you are safe from ppl getting hold of your keys.

Make sure that you are keep really good track of what is being committed to git and what is not. Specially things like androidmanifest, googleservices etc have to be within your .gitignore.